# How would I alter HTML displayed in VB.net application using Gecko

Tags: html, css, vb.net, gecko

I would like to know how I would go about altering the HTML that is displayed by my VB.net application using GeckoFX.  What I would like to do restrict certain words/names/attributes from showing in the browser.

Any info/links would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi my name is Hello from Google.com! ... Just kidding, you should check the svn of GeckoFX and see if they can help you.